# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null (infinite loop)

Tags: angular, typescript

The problem is that when the field is null it is in the infinite loop. I was unable to identify how to fix this bug. This problem is giving only one specific service.

**ERROR:**

```
ItemDetalheComponent.html: 54 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
at ItemDetalheComponent.linkItens (item-detail.component.ts: 60)
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ItemDetalheComponent.html: 54)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js: 45294)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js: 44277)
at callViewAction (core.js: 44637)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js: 44594)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js: 44272)
at callViewAction (core.js: 44637)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js: 44594)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js: 44272)
```

**This is line 60**

```
linkItens(numeroItens: string): string {
    const numeroItensTratados = numeroItens.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
    return `https://teste/#/resultado/${numeros}`;
}
```

My idea would be to change from null to empty, maybe that will stop bringing this error. If anyone can help me at least go the right way, I appreciate it.

Comment: where do you call `linkItens`, why are you sending it null instead of a string.

Comment: do you speak in HTML or in the TS file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use empty string if `numeroItens` is null

```
const numeroItensTratados = (numeroItens || '').replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
```